# Firefox clips edge of select when wrapped in div with overflow

Tags: css, firefox

I'm on Firefox 65 and OSX 10.11.6 and in the following snippet I am seeing the border missing from the left edge of the `<select>` element:

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
}

select {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>TEST123</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

For those on a different browser or configuration it looks like this:

[image: cropped select menu]

Can anyone explain why the browser is rendering the element without the left side border? Is this a bug or is there some legitimate reason why that combination of rules should yield this result?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is the overflow that is causing this to happen.  Removing that declaration seems to fix it.

Not sure why this is happening though.

```css
div {
  overflow: initial;
}

select {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>TEST123</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Also, it's not the border that is falling off.  If you set the border to be 1px red, you get the image attached.

[image: border:1px solid red]

At this point, I think it's the browser native box shadow that is getting cut off.

Comment: Searching for a reason why.  Haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Thanks, Jennifer, as mentioned in the question title, I'm aware that the `overflow` rule is a contributing factor here so this really doesn't answer the question but thanks all the same.